# I'm trying to add 25 every-time a user inputs "Yes" and then print the results but it keeps missing the first response when adding them up

Tags: java

I'm trying to add 25 every-time a user inputs "Yes" and then print the results but it keeps missing the first response when adding them up. So if I type "Yes" for dairy I'm only getting 75%? It's a work in progress for larger piece of code but basically at the moment if you type "Yes" for dairy then it should add them all up and equal a 100.

Tried so many different options and have gotten no where

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner userTypes = new Scanner(System.in); //new object for user input
            String[] respondents = {"Cormac", "Orla", "Paul", "Sarah"};
            String[] questions = {"Are you allergic to Dairy?", "Are you allergic to nuts?", "Are you gluten intolerent?"};
            String[] decisions = new String [4];
            int dairy= 0;
            int nuts= 0;
            int gluten=0;           
            for (int i=0; i<= respondents.length -1 ;i++) {
                System.out.println(respondents[i]);         
                for (int j=0; j<= questions.length -1; j++) {
                    System.out.println(questions[j]);
                    decisions[j]=userTypes.nextLine();    
                    }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decisions));
            }
            System.out.println("Allergy Results");              
            for (int k=0; k <= respondents.length - 1; k++ ){                   
                if (decisions[k].equals("Yes")) {
                    dairy= dairy + 25;                      
                }    
            }    
            System.out.println("Dairy Allergy Results = " + dairy + "%");
        }    
}
```

Comment: Your text uses "if then" language, but your code only loops over data. Shouldn't there be some if in your code then?

Comment: There is an `if` inside the second loop, counting the number of times `"Yes"` occurs.

Comment: you have 4 users and 3 questions, so in total you should have 12 decisions, but you're allocating array for 4, this means that some answers are lost

Comment: I'd replace line `decisions[j]=userTypes.nextLine();` with `if (j==0) decisions[i]=userTypes.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, lets format the code. For storing the decision of 4 different users for 3 three different questions, you need your array (data structure) to be like that. Also, looks like you are only interested (for now) in the decision about the dairy question. So, just check for that in your calculation. I have updated the code and added the comments. Need to update the part where you are storing the results and how you are calculating the total for dairy.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userTypes = new Scanner(System.in); //new object for user input
        String[] respondents = {"Cormac", "Orla", "Paul", "Sarah"};
        String[] questions = {"Are you allergic to Dairy?", "Are you allergic to nuts?", "Are you gluten intolerent?"};
        String[][] decisions = new String [4][3];//You have 4 respondents and You have 3 questions
        int dairy= 0;
        int nuts= 0;
        int gluten=0;
        for (int i=0; i<= respondents.length -1 ;i++) {
            System.out.println(respondents[i]);
            for (int j=0; j<= questions.length -1; j++) {
                System.out.println(questions[j]);
                decisions[i][j]=userTypes.nextLine();
                }
            System.out.println("Decisions :: "+Arrays.toString(decisions[i]));//Need to print the result per user
        }
        System.out.println("Allergy Results");//If you are only interested in dairy decision for the 4 user
        for (int k=0; k <= respondents.length - 1; k++ ){
            if (decisions[k][0].equals("Yes")) {//for all user check the first decision (as your first question is about dairy)
                dairy= dairy + 25;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Dairy Allergy Results = " + dairy + "%");           
        userTypes.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that for every respondent, you are recording their answers in `decisions[j]` where `j` is the question number; but then later you are counting the number of "Yes" responses by iterating over `decisions[k]` where `k` is the respondent number.

Either `decisions[i]` means some respondent's answer to question `i`, or it means the `i`th respondent's answer to question 1. It cannot mean both. You need to reconsider how you are storing this data.

Furthermore, since `decisions[j]` is being written for each `j` for each respondent, the array is overwritten each time, meaning you only end up storing the results for the last respondent.

A two-dimensional array may be a good solution, where `decisions[i][j]` means the `i`th respondent's answer to question `j`.

Comment: Probably right but 2d array sounds way out of my understanding right now, I'll go back to the drawing board

Comment: Alternatively, if you only need to compute the percentage for question 1, you can use a one-dimensional array like you have, but its length should be the number of participants (not the number of questions), and you will need an `if` statement in the first loop to make sure you only write to the array when the respondent is answering question 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my really basic solution in the end was the below, not ideal but hey I'm a beginner:)

```
public class question4 {
        static void allergyTest() { //method for the allergy test
            Scanner userTypes = new Scanner(System.in); //new object for user input
            String[] respondents = {"Cormac", "Orla", "Paul", "Sarah"};//string array that contains the name of the people being surveyed 
            String[] questions = {"Are you allergic to Dairy?", "Are you allergic to nuts?", "Are you gluten intolerent?"};// string array to store the questions
            String[] decisions = new String [3];//string array to store the responses to the questions
            int dairy= 0; //int to store dairy percentage
            int nuts= 0;// int to store nuts percentage
            int gluten=0; //int to store gluten percentage

            for (int i=0; i<= respondents.length -1 ;i++) { // for loop to go through each respondent
                System.out.println(respondents[i]); //print their name

                for (int j=0; j<= questions.length -1; j++) { //then a for loop to loop through the questions for each respondent 
                    System.out.println(questions[j]); //print the actual question
                    decisions[j]=userTypes.nextLine(); //take the users input

                    while(!decisions[j].equals("yes")&& !decisions[j].equals("no")) { //check if the users input is valid, as in yes or no
                        System.out.println("please type yes or no as your answer"); //if not tell them to type it correctly
                        decisions[j]=userTypes.nextLine(); //store the yes or no once correctly typed 
                    }

                }

                if (decisions[0].equals("yes")) { //add up the yes
                    dairy = dairy +25; //lazy way of getting a percentage because I know the amount of respondents & answers
                }
                if (decisions[1].equals("yes")) {
                    nuts = nuts +25;
                }
                if (decisions[2].equals("yes")) {
                    gluten = gluten +25;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Allergy Results");// print the results below
            System.out.println("Percentage of people allergic to dairy= "+ dairy +"%");
            System.out.println("Percentage of people allergic to nuts= "+ nuts +"%");
            System.out.println("People who think they are allergic to gluten= "+ gluten +"%");


        }


        public static void main(String[] args) { //call the allergy test
            allergyTest();


        }
}
```